# C# ExchangeService, Is It possible to get original mail in case of bounce back?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using ExchangeService to read a mailbox from EWS server. If I use EAGetMail than I am able to see original mail recipients but in case of ExchangeService I am unable to track anything about original mail therefor anyone can let me know If it is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the original message headers which are actually stored as ItemAttachment in the bounced e-mail.

Comment: Attachments count is always 0. I am using code : EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(serviceInstance, msg.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));